# An error using \mathit

Tags: math-mode, boxes

A command is defined in the preamble to typeset the arc symbol over a pair of letters or a triple of letters.  `WinEdt` compiles `$\arc{AB}$` but not `$\arc{\mathit{AB}}$`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}



\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,tipa}
%This command typesets an arc symbol over letters.
\newcommand{\arc}[1]{%
  \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%
  \ooalign{\resizebox{\wd9}{\height}{\texttoptiebar{\phantom{A}}}\cr#1}}



\begin{document}

%$\arc{\mathit{AB}}$ \\
$\arc{AB}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\arc{$\mathit{AB}$}`, perhaps.

Comment: It's not WinEdt, it's your code...!

Comment: @Werner  How about telling me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: `\hbox` expects text mode, and `\mathit` expects math mode, so their contradictory.

Comment: @egreg  Yes, you are right.  I copied the `newcommand{\arc}[1]` from another member from `texstackexchange`.  Is what is put in `{}` in text mode?

Comment: @Werner  OK.  I was asking egreg the question that you were answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%
```

typesets `#1` in text mode you probably want

```
\setbox8=\hbox{$#1$}%
```

(use even scratch registers for local assignment)

Comment: Yep.  That is what I have been told.